# Как быстро обновляется информация пользователя после получения знака?

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Недавно получил знак "Главред" :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но он не появился в списке знаков по классу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в статус баре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я вообще думал что оно сразу обновится, но почему-то нет. Пробовал с очисткой кэша, но тоже не помогло. Для справки - вопрос связан не с тем почему мне медальку не выдали, а по юзабилити данного ресурса, а то я знаю сейчас в комментах начнется :) Либо я чего-то не понял и это поведение нормальное

Comment: Возможно, надо сутки подождать.

Comment: ааа, ну тогда ладно) я просто думал что оно прям быстро обновится, может тогда ночью будет синхронизация проходить и все подтянется